# Cryptopp make ARM 32bit shared library

Tags: c++, linux, build, crypto++

I'm new in Linux and Ubuntu and I need to build cryptopp library by ARM32.
I've been following [ARM Embedded(Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_(Command_Line))'s **Install the Package**, **Set the Environment**, **Build the Library** section

Belows are what I did

**git clone cryptopp**

> $> git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
> $> cd cryptopp

**Install the Package section**

> $> sudo apt-get update
> $> sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

**Set the Environment section**
I opened `./cryptopp/TestScript/setenv-embedded.sh` and modified below values

> ARM_EMBEDDED_CXXFLAGS="-|/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/7.5.0 -|/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/7.5.0/arm-linux-gnueabi"
> ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi"
> ARM_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION="7.5.0"

**Build the Library section**

> $> run source ./TestScript/setenv-embedded.sh
> $> sudo make -f GNUmakefile-cross static dynamic cryptest.exe

I tried above, however, build runs with ***g++*** not ***arm-linux-gnueabi-g++*** like below

> g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 - fPIC - pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
> g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 - fPIC - pipe -c cpu.cpp
> ...

and result shared library was '64bit x86-64' version.
I'd like to make cryptopp shared library with 32bit arm architecture.

Anyone help me or share helpful link please?

### Solved

I referred to @Anton Malyshev's answer and solved it.

As he said, changing g++ to arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ is perfectly worked.
For how, this is my solution(If there is better things, please share it)

1. Open ***GNUmakefile-cross** file* and add `CXX := arm-linux-gnueabi-g++`
2. Run sudo make -f GNUmakefile-cross static dynamic cryptest.exe
   that's it.

But I don't know why it didn't work even I had followed cryptopp's wiki

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you just need to use `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi` instead of `g++`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the solution by your answer.

Comment: Feel free to edit / extend the answer to describe the actual solution